# Is cleaning silverware with tinfoil and salt dangerous?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning, silver

Premise: I'm not a chemist and I've already had a look at [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/what-happens-during-cleaning-silverware) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/what-is-the-chemistry-behind-cleaning-silverware-with-aluminium-foil) but they don't fully answer my question.

I have read that you can clean silverware using tinfoil, salt and water, though from what I understand, $\ce{H2S}$ is (or could be?) freed. Again, from what I understand, this a dangerous compound to breath. Now, is it still safe to clean silverware using this method? Is the amount of $\ce{H2S}$ freed dangerous?

I don't want to come across a "bleach + vinegar situation", which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Many things are unsafe if you do them incorrectly, unfortunately. If you perform the reaction in a well ventilated place you reduce the risk effectively to near zero. The answer presumably  also depends on the amount of silverware and the state of the silverware.

Comment: I've used this method several times. You'll need to make sure your silver is in very good contact with the tinfoil so wrap it quite tightly. I do not recall ever smelling H2S from the system

Comment: 1. The amount of sulfur in the tarnish is microscopic. 2. Much of it reacts with the Al, and is not released as a gas. Consider that there is cyanide bound in almonds and apple seeds. Eating them in reasonable amounts is *usually* not fatal. *There have been exceptions.*